# Crop the image for special path

Tags: android, image, crop

I have a list of special items: in left side foto and in right side of item some text. Under the list background with special texture. Image should be crop in the form of a pentagon. Haw to crop the image and not to disrupt the texture under it?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that create an image however you want to crop your image, i mean as it's mask and put it on your imageView... And then set your imageView which is below mask. So it'll seem like your image's been croped.